# Replace "Compress" in Finder context menu with other compression app

Tags: error, compression, archive-utility

I've lost some sensitive data because the built-in compression utility generates corrupt files and doesn't show any error.

After I compressed about 1 Gb of files with Finder's "Compress", I decided to delete the original data just to find that the file was corrupt and couldn't be extracted. This have happened to me acouple of times.

Is there a way to change the default behavior to show errors during compressing or to replace zip from the compress contextual menu?

Comment: I never had an issue with the Compress option (which is based on zip actually). Did you try to unzip the compressed files with another zip tool to see whether this works better?

Comment: @patrix hmm... Pacifist can't open the file, and BetterZip says it's password protected, I didn't pasword protected that file, weird.

Comment: Ok, it definitively **is** corrupt. Now back to your question: Are you more interested in getting the corrupted zip repaired or do you want an alternative? If both, please consider a new question for the repairing part.

Comment: @patrix Oh, it would be great if it can be repaired I 'll google that later. So, is there a way to change the default behavior or to replace zip from the compress contextual menu?

Comment: I've edited the question a bit to make it more easy to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here; maybe if the compression utility supports command line so you can create a service script and maybe assign a keyboard shortcut to it or access it from Finder>Services?

Answer (score 2):

[BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com) includes a service for compressing files:

[image]

You might also just use `zip` or `tar` from the command line:

```
zip directory.zip directory
COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar -czf directory.tgz directory
```

Note that `zip` currently removes [extended attributes and ACLs](https://superuser.com/questions/61185).

Comment: What is `COPYFILE_DISABLE` for? Can I just use `tar -czf directory.tgz` directory?

Comment: @rraallvv See the question I linked to. It tells tar to remove extended attributes and ACLs instead of using the AppleDouble format.